# Generate PBKDF sha512 hash in Node verifiable by passlib.hash.pbkdf2_sha512

Tags: encryption, sha512, pbkdf2

I am using `passlib` `pbkdf2_sha512` on my python api to verify a users password. The input string that the algorithm needs has to follow this format as far as I am aware: `$pbkdf2-digest$rounds$salt$checksum`

Is there a library in Node that can generate me a sha512 password and return it in such format or would I need to write my own algorithm to format it in such way and pick random salts, rounds etc.

More information about the [python library](https://passlib.readthedocs.io/en/1.6.5/lib/passlib.hash.pbkdf2_digest.html).

I tried to reproduce the String generated by the python library in Node:

```
function sha512(password) {
  const salt = crypto.randomBytes(16);

  const rounds = 29000;

  // I used sha256 for testing purpose, it shouldn't matter for the sake of the result
  const passwordHashed = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, salt, rounds, 256, 
  'sha256').toString('Base64');

  console.log(passwordHashed);
}
```

I generated a hash for "password" and my code returns
Encoded in Base64:

```
7uLTDHjAhQX0yIqXptXuhHIygNogaZRcDqa7ckc0XCj4FAAW29V6KzIzRuJKJoTqN9xjfGOyGZ21X0J1vemQLThcnIXgwt2E84VrW/ai+BdVaUPHiT8J0mutOM9j52l1fFLT7rl5Rmr8qiyGzBaWj6i0sRkrdba9IVDHr1HxGAoM8qEuCSHgKsBVVX65+1pf2DDEUsgGShzE31xiuwF8UpHwq5Cxhiq8ER5xQnKj/j3mG/AAoylPVu30Jd4aFNoRi2Lfhk+6nFwLS0R222R38Jio93qzVD0Nb8kjXqjoXIYxTY6ZOumlsXWR/NmhTQi31x6JggoO1Z1jSFnCVUUd2Q==
```

And when generated with the python library in adept base 64

```
98jZicV16ODfEsEZeYPGHU3kbrUrvUEXOPimVSQDD44
```

Which is obviously a much smaller String. The library mentions that their encode is very basic except for some characters being swapped but this result doesn't seem to make quite sense to me. (I used the same salt size and the same rounds as in the exmample on the library website)

Comment: I don't know if there is a Node lib that produces this format, but you could use `crypto.pbkdf2()` to create the checksum part, then base64-encode it and add the other parts.

Comment: I was going to but the python library uses [adapted base64 encoding](https://passlib.readthedocs.io/en/1.6.5/lib/passlib.utils.html#passlib.utils.ab64_encode)

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem. You could just replace `+` with `.` and remove the padding, if there isn't a Node method that supports this encoding.

Comment: I adjusted my post and added an example of what happens when I use node encoding @t.m.adam

Comment: That's because you've set the `keylen` parameter to 256 bytes. This parameter expects bytes not bits, so your Node code produced a much larger key.

Comment: right, so it should be 32 instead then

Comment: Yes, just make sure you have the same values you have in your Python code. I would provide a full answer but don't have this Python module installed, to verify the Node code. However it should be pretty easy to produce this format with Node.